# How to know whether navigation back is clicked?

Tags: android

I have added a PreferenceScreen in my application that include back navigation. When I click the navigation icon, it doesn't save what I make in PreferenceScreen. So, how can I handle navigation back click.

Comment: Try overriding onBackPressed of the Activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply override the `onBackPressed`...

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     // code here to save the change
     super.onBackPressed();  // optional depending on your needs
}
```

As PreferenceActivity is a subclass of Activity, it should follow the same lifecycle. Click on the link and then navigate to Indirect Subclasses or here is the direct http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html

**Edits**

In your case you are using the as parent activity to MainActivity, that's why it is getting re-created when you press the navigation back. remove the line from manifest.

```
           <activity
                android:name=".UserSettingActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" 
  (remove this line) android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            </activity>
```

and change the code of your settings Activity as ..

```
public class UserSettingActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.user_settings);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         switch (item.getItemId()) {
          case android.R.id.home:

              Log.e("onOptionsItemSelected", "home");
              finish();
          return false;
       }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: It works only for back button.What I want is when back navigation(<back)is clicked,how can I know.

Comment: are you using `android:parentActivityName` in manifest. I mean, are you using navigation Up ..like: as `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`?

Comment: I am just a begineer and so I don't know much about android.In the upper link,I upload my work.What I want is when I click back navigation(not back menu),I want to change the textview's text according to the change in setting.That is all I want.Thank in advance.

Comment: Yes,it work.Could you please tell me why it work?It would be a great help.

Comment: In your case you are using the as parent activity to MainActivity, that's why your preferance activity launching your main activity as new Intent Activity, when you press the navigation back button. that is the cause of re- Creation of your MainAcivity (calling its OnCreate() method ). And you set the data in OnActivityResult. Thats why your text views were resetting.